# Visual Studio Code: Error include external header in C

Tags: c, json, visual-studio-code, header, fatal-error

New to programming, actually following an open classroom tutorial on C and I'm finding myself stuck on that including external header part. I use an IDE, I'm on Visual Studio Code, I could switch to an IDE but it should be possible and not to difficult to do it in a simple text editor so I want to understand how.

The error code when running the program:

```
main.c:6:10: fatal error: 'level.h' file not found
#include "level.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

Here's my `main.c` code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "level.h"
#include "menu.h"

int level();
int menu();
int main()
{
    int nombreMystere, guess, round = 10;
    char answer;
    bool exit = true;
    while (exit)
    {
        menu();
        {       
            while(guess != nombreMystere)
            {      
                printf("%d"                          , nombreMystere);
                printf("\nIl vous restes %d round.\n", round        );
                printf("Trouver le nombre magique: "                );
                scanf ("%d"                          , &guess       );
                if(guess < nombreMystere) printf("Trop bas\n"); 
                else if(guess > nombreMystere) printf("Trop Haut\n"); 

                round --;
                if (round == 0)
                {
                    printf("You Lose.. Dumbass");
                    break;
                }
                if (guess == nombreMystere)  printf("\nGood job !\n");
            }

            printf("Play again?\n (yes/no): ");

            scanf("%s", &answer);
            if (answer == 110 || answer == 78) {exit=0;}
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here's `level.c`:

```
static int selec;

int level(int x)
{
    int max, difficulty = selec;

    if      (difficulty==1){max    = 100                                ;}
    else if (difficulty==2){max    = 1000                               ;}
    else if (difficulty==3){max    = 10000                              ;}
    return max;
}
```

`level.h`:

```
int level(int x);
```

`menu.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "menu.h"
int level();
int menu()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int  max, nombreMystere, selec;
    const int MIN = 1;
    while (selec < 1 || selec > 3)

            {
                printf("\n\nSelect Difficulty level:\n");
                printf("1: Level 1\n");
                printf("2: Level 2\n");
                printf("3: Level 3\n");
                scanf("%d", &selec);
                level(selec);
                printf("\n\n%d\n\n", max);
                //if      (difficulty==1){max    = 100                                ;}
                //else if (difficulty==2){max    = 1000                               ;}
                //else if (difficulty==3){max    = 10000                              ;}
                //else                   {printf("Wrong selection, please try again.");}
                nombreMystere = (rand() % (max - MIN + 1)) + MIN;
            }
    return nombreMystere;
}
```

`menu.h`:

```
int menu();
```

I've been searching the whole day on the internet a way to fix this issue but I don't understand half of what I'm seeing and every topic was talking only about C++. I've seen somewhere that it could come from the `tasks.json` file in VSCode but it was on a C++ topic.

> I'm using macOS.

Thanks for your time.

> > EDIT: Both .h and .c files are in separate folders and both folders are in the same directory.

Comment: Make sure the `level.h` exists in the same directory where the main code exists.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, yes they are all in the same directory.

Comment: How are you doing your compilations?  Are you using the IDE or running them from a bash prompt?  If you are doing it from a bash prompt, how are you running it?

Comment: From the visual studio code run option.

Answer (score 0):

The `level.h` file needs to be in the **SAME** folder as `main.c`.

Also the `menu.h` file should be in the same folder. So make sure you have all the files in the same folder.

Additionally these two lines shouldn't be in your `main.c`:

```
int level();
int menu();
```

Since this is essentially what including the headers does for you. On that note I also can't see you calling the function `level()` in your `main.c` file, thus you do not even need to include the `level.h` file at all. However you do call the function `menu()` so you do need to `#include "menu.h"` like you are doing.

Also in the `menu.c` file you don't need this line `#include "menu.h"`, you should change it to `#include "level.h"` since you are calling the `level()` function in your code and then also remove the line after it, that is; the line `int level();`, since that's essentially what including the level header will do for you.

The `level.c` file looks fine to me.

If you're still getting an error with all the files in the same folder, make sure you are compiling it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In `include "x"` the value of `x` represents the path to your header file (relative using the directories `.` and `..` in your current directory or absolute paths, the latter is a **BAD PRACTICE** don't do it, but you can, side note: the `~` is not supported) if all your files are in the same directory you shouldn't have such an error, you don't have to use the relative path it assumes the current directory by default, but if they aren't consider including them the right way. see sveinnth's answer for more notes about your coding style.

one more thing, you should include your compilation options in your question.